# How to arrange an array in descending order alongside a string array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

here is my code... I need all the contestants to be ranked according to their votes... as you can see there are seperate arrays for the names and vote count(tally)... I was told that bubble sort would work but i cant see how because bubble sort replaces the insides so if tally[2] is greater than tally[1], it will become the new tally[1] meanwhile the name stays the same as name[1] does not change with name[2]...I would prefer that you use basic codes as i am a total noob with programming and have only recently started...also, any recommendations about how i can write my code better/shorter is appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
public class FroshNight {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dec = "0";
    System.out.println("How many blocks?");
    int contno = sc.nextInt();
    int winner = 0;
    String winname = "a";
    String[] code = new String[contno];
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    String[] contname = new String[contno];
    int[] tally = new int[contno];
    while (counter<contno) {
        System.out.print("Name of Pair:");
        contname[counter]=sc.next();
        counter++;
    }
    counter=0;
    while (counter<contno) {
        System.out.println("Choose a vote code for "+ contname[counter]+"(must not be x)");
        code[counter] = sc.next();


        counter++;
    }
    boolean stop = false;

    counter=0;
    while(stop == false){
        System.out.println("Input Vote (x to exit): ");
        dec = sc.next();
        if(dec.equals("x")) {
            stop = true;

        }
        counter = 0;
        while(counter<contno){  

            if(dec.equals(code[counter])){
                tally[counter] +=1;
                counter = contno;

            }
            counter++;
        }

    }
    //>> aft. else
    counter = 0;
    while(counter<contno){
        total += tally[counter];
        counter++;
        ;
    }
    counter=0;
    while(counter<contno){
        if(tally[counter]>winner){
            winner = tally[counter];
            winname = contname[counter];
        }
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.print("The Winner is: "+ winname +" - "+winner );
    System.out.println("("+((double)winner/total)*100+"%)");

    counter = 0;
    while (counter<contno) {
        System.out.print(contname[counter]+" - Score:");
        System.out.print(tally[counter]);
        System.out.println("("+((double)tally[counter]/total)*100+"%)");

        counter++;

    }

    //>>> end while

    // add rankings here^^
}

    }
```

Comment: Methods... More methods... heh

Comment: As @austinwernli said, you should definitely use methods.

Comment: Makes no sense to have an array of scores and an array of associated names. It just makes things more complicated. Create a class named like `Contestant` that holds both values and put in a single array, then sort it using an appropriate `Comparator` class. Also btw, in Java you rarely use arrays but `List` instead.